# how to turn off power save mode in ILCE-QX1 camera using SDK?

Tags: json, sdk, camera, sony-camera-api, power-saving

I am using the Sony SDK to develop a solution using the ILCE-QX1 camera.  I need to keep the camera powered up at all times but sometimes the camera will power down if the network connection has a glitch.  There is no way in the SDK that I have found to tell the camera to not power down.  I am using the camera with the AC adapter so the camera always has good power.

Comment: Got any luck Chris? I am currently experiencing the same issue. I need to keep the ICE-QX1 Camera on. I must deactivate power saving mode which apparently is not possible through the SDK https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/. Check out : [Sony Camera Development allowed features](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eMIHc.jpg)

Comment: Camilo, no luck via SDK.  Best I  have done is keep pinging the camera to keep it alive so it does not power down.  Still an issue if lose wireless connection for a brief time.